# How to setup Facebook application activity custom events? Can be done on server?

Tags: facebook, expo

Please note that this question is about [Facebook Application Activity events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/activities/#overview), not about <strike>[Facebook events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event)</strike>.

I have a client app made with Expo SDK37. The app is already using the [Facebook SDK from the package provided by expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/facebook/) to allow users to sign-in/up using a facebook account - which works great. However, no other APIs are available with the expo facebook package, as stated by the expo docs:

> Expo exposes a minimal native API since you can access Facebook's Graph API directly through HTTP (using fetch, for example).

I am having troubles with integrating the Application acitivity APIs.
I would like to send custom events from the app so that they can be seen in the application dashboard of the facebook app. I am calling the appropriate Graph APIs, and I always get a response of `{ success: true }`. But nothing new appears in the dashboard or in the `Facebook Analytics` product, even after a day (a note says an event could take up to 20 minutes to show up in the analytics).
I have also switched to making tests using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), and i get the same results.

These are the URLs of the requests I am making to the Facebook Activities Graph API:

```
// Get an application access token
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10&grant_type=client_credentials
// response
{ access_token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", token_type: "bearer" }

// Send a custom event
POST https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/activities?event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS&custom_events=[{ name: "TEST_EVENT" }]&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
// response
{ success: true }
```

*The application id and other sensitive details have been masked*

And, as I said, nothing new appears in the dashboard:

[image: Analytics dashboard events]

Does anyone have any idea how to correctly setup these APIs and the facebook application?

Also, the second related question: is it possible to use these APIs server-side?

Comment: `&cusom_events=[{ name: "TEST_EVENT" }]` – you did spell that parameter name correctly in your actual requests though, yes?

Comment: _“is it possible to use these APIs server-side?”_ - didn’t _“you can access Facebook's Graph API directly through HTTP”_ kinda answer that question already?

Comment: The event name is specified as either "name" or "_eventName", depending whether you look at the Activity events or Marketing APIs - although, they both use the same events.
I don't know if the value "TEST_EVENT" is to be configured anywhere in the facebook app.
The question about using these APIs server-side is because the Facebook docs always mention using the Facebook SDK in an Android/iOS/web environment. There is no documentation on using it server-side.

Comment: I was referring to `&cusom_events=` …

Comment: As far as I could read in the documentation, sending custom events works by setting a parameter `event` to `CUSTOM_EVENT`, and by including a parameter `custom_events` with an array of events, where each event requires at least a `name` field. I think I have understood this right, but let me know if you understand it differenty.

Comment: `cusom_events` != `custom_events`

Comment: Oh, that's just a typo in writing the post here, in the actual code is spelled correctly.